# How to Calculate the total cost of this specific item

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate the total amount 'spent' on this item.

```
baseCost = 32;
upgrade.baseCost + (32 * 0)
upgrade.baseCost + (32 * 1)
upgrade.baseCost + (32 * 2)
//...
upgrade.baseCost + (32 * 100)
total = ?;
```

Output should be every 'cost' from 0-100 so I can count the total amount 'spent' on the upgrade. So i want to add upgrade.baseCost + (32 * 0) + upgrade.baseCost + (32 * 1) + upgrade.baseCost + (32 * 2)... Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you need help with

Comment: Sorry, new to stack, hopefully the edit helped clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure if this is what you want ... but you could use a simple for loop and execute it as often as you like and calculate a value for each iteration, save it in a variable and display it in the end.

```js
var upgrade = {baseCost: 32};

var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  total += upgrade.baseCost + (32 * i);
}

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate numbers 0 through 100, or rather 1 through 100. Therefore:

**The imperative way:**

```
const baseCost = 42;
let total = 0;
for(let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) { // 0-100
    total += upgrade.baseCost + 32 * i;
}
```

**Note**: you can skip the first iteration of `0` because that has no effect on your total sum.

**A more functional (ES6) way:**

```
const total = Array.from(Array(100).keys()).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + upgrade.baseCost + (32 * (currentValue + 1)), 0); 
// creates an array of length 100, zero-indexed so we need to add one to the current number while we add and at the same time avoiding baseCost * 0.
```

`Array.from`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

`Array.keys`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys

`Array.reduce`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce